# Setting parts of a String to Bold in UIView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uiview, string-formatting, html-encode

I'm parsing an XML file an get a string as `NSMutableString`.
Now I want to show this string as text in my `UIView`.
So, I created a `TextView` and set its value to my string. The result was that I have the text with HTML Tags shown up in the TextView.

There is no problem removing the tags from the string, but some of the text needs to appear as bold.

Is there any way to display parts of a string as bold programmatically?

I replaced `<br>` Elements with `\n`  and it works fine for line-break.

But I still don't know what I can do to display words between strong tags as bold in the `UIView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways. The first is by displaying them in UIWebViews; prior to iOS 4.1 this was effectively the only way. Because you already have HTML codes in the text, it would certainly be easy.

If you're ok with your app running only on iOS 4.1 and up you can use Core Text, which provides very rich formatting.

**EDIT**

Apple provides some good resources:

[About Text, Web, and Editing Support in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[Core Text Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533)

[WWDC 2010 Session Videos](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) -- follow the link to iTunes and grab session 110: Advanced Text Handling for iPhone OS
(Apple Developer login required)

Comment: Hey, thx for your answer. But in UIWebView I can't use the other obj-c features anymore, right? The App is already working on the latest iOS SDK. Can you give me some good source link for Core Text?

Comment: Well, you're dealing with rendering of HTML text, but you have access to the text and can do most anything you'd want, albeit awkwardly. I added a few links that should help. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You may use UIWebView and load your content from an NSString object.

Anyway if you want to stick to Cocoa, have a look to NSAttributedString.