# How to make part of a textView text bigger and bold?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I don't even know how to make all of the textView bold, but I want to know how to make only a word in the whole text to be like a title (bigger and bold).

```
mytextview.text = @"Title \n text text text text";  

//I want the "Title" to be bigger and bold
```

Comment: You can not with a singe textView, use two

Comment: Perhaps the following article could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346075/setting-parts-of-a-string-to-bold-in-uiview

Comment: @TeofiloIsraelVizcainoRodrig I can't use two because my text is big, and the work that I want to make bold and bigger is in the middle of it...

Comment: Then check answers and comments in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454067/display-html-text-in-uitextview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use attributed string and render with core text framework.[stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322020/display-nsattributedstring-using-coretext)
or you can use cocoanetics core text component [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText).